# Instant reverse dependencies between classes in visual paradigm

Tags: java, uml, visual-paradigm

I would like to reverse dependencies between my java classes using visual paradigm.

Is there any way to do it ? Or any other UML modeling tool that could achieve that ?

[image]

Comment: *dependencies between my java classes* :  what are you speaking about, inheritances and attributes, or dependencies in the UML definition ? For the inheritances and attributes any reverse will produce them, so very probably visual paradigm.

Comment: I updated my post, this kind of "use" dependency seems hard to find in reverse tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do not want to 'reverse' the dependencies from sources but to have them produced in addition during/after the reverse, I mean a dependency is not an element present in the sources like a class.

"use" can signify a lot of things, like somewhere in *Client* the class *Supplier* is used to type an attribute and/or the return value or parameter(s) of  operation(s) and/or or inside the definitions of an operation etc.

For me you have to add them by hand or helped by the tool **when it is necessary**, I mean to have a dependency in all the cases is just a way to have plenty of dependencies creating a spider web / noodle dish, you must *not* do that.

Referring to [Visualize the Dependencies between Elements](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/447/449/20237_analyzingamo.html) on the class *Client* call the menu and choose the entry *related element > analysis* 
[image]

then use the toggles to select the kind of 'use' you want
[image]

Also look at [How to Visualize Model Dependencies with Analysis Diagram?](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/impactanalysiswithanalysis.jsp)